# Media Query Wont Edit Photo

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move my image based on screen width but my media query for it wont work. I've checked multiple websites and watched many youtube videos but I don't see any problems with the code here's
an example code:

```
 .bg{
  position:absolute:top:100px;left:10px
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 776px){
  .bg{
  position:absolute;top:10px:left:5px;
  }
  }
```

Thought maybe I was missing a specific header or my editor wasn't working but don't think either of that is a problem.

Comment: Typo in `position:absolute:`

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 776px) {
    .bg {
        position:absolute;
        top:10px;
        left:5px;
    }
}
```

`;` but not `:`